# Declaring VBA Array and If Function

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am beginner with VBA and I need your help for some issues.

You will find my code below. I get a compile error with `Mtable`.

Thanks.

```
Sub GatheringofExpense()

    Dim Branches As Worksheet
    Dim Final As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lrow As Range
    Dim lcol As Range

    Set Branches = Worksheets("Branches")
    Set Final = Worksheets("Final")

    'Defining last row and last column in the table for our Array
    lrow = Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
    lcol = Range("XFD4").End(xlToLeft).Column

    Mtable = Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(lrow, lcol))  'Assigning  array for table

    For i = 1 To UBound(Mtable, 1)
        If Branches.Range("A" & i)="Barda" And Range("B" & i)="Fuzuli" Then
           Range("A" & i).End(xlToRight).Copy
           Final.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You never declared `Mtable`. Good practice is to use `Option Explicit` at the top of all of your modules. In any event -- you have declared `lrow` and `lcol` to be `Range` but are treating them as if they were `Long`. Also -- don't use `Integer` for row indices. It isn't large enough of a data type for all possible rows. Use `Long` instead.

Comment: Thanks for comment. How must I declare Mtable correctly?

Comment: The code that you have above doesn't throw a *compile* error. Are you sure that it isn't a run-time error? If so -- what does the error message actually say?

Comment: @JohnColeman If throws Compile Errors when I click "compile" on it (with or without Option Explicit)

Comment: @ashleedawg When I copy paste the exact code above, and tack on `End Sub` then I don't get compile errors (when `Option Explicit` is turned off).

Comment: @JohnColeman -I stand corrected, I must have had an `Explicit` hiding somewhere.  "Compile error: variable not defined" *with* Option Explicit...  (The OP could have that line too - no reason to assume th example is the entire module.)

Comment: After declare Mtable as variant my code worked properly. Problem was that I dindn't know how to declare array.

Comment: @Khazar If you don't declare a variable then it implicitly *is* variant already, so I somewhat skeptical of your description of the problem and its solution. Perhaps you had a *global* declaration of `Mtable` that was of an inconsistent type.

Comment: @Khazar - what happens if your `Activesheet` is not `"Branches"`?

Comment: @JohnColeman - Actually right now my code doesn't show any error but   it doesn't work. I mean it does not finalize the process. Does not copy and paste the lines.

Comment: @paulbica - you are right. I solved it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Option Explicit`, change `Int` to `Long`, declare array as `Variant`, and qualify all ranges

Try this

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GatheringOfExpense()
    Dim branches As Worksheet, final As Worksheet, lRow As Long, lCol As Long

    Set branches = Worksheets("Branches")
    Set final = Worksheets("Final")

    With branches   'Define last row and last column in "Branches" sheet, for our Array
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Dim tblArr As Variant, nextRow As Long, r As Long

        tblArr = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))   'Assig array to table
        nextRow = final.Cells(final.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For r = 1 To UBound(tblArr)
            If tblArr(r, 1) = "Barda" And tblArr(r, 2) = "Fuzuli" Then
               .Cells(r + 4 - 1, lCol).Copy
                final.Cells(nextRow, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                nextRow = nextRow + 1
            End If
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed somethings you mentioned on your code without fully copied your code. Now Everything is working properly.
I used option explicit, declare my array as variant, lrow lcol as long and changed int to long. Thanks for your help.